# How to change windows resource at runtime

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm writing a directdraw wrapper in order to get one old game working in modern windows. I need to hide the system cursor, but I can't use ShowCursor (as I need to know when the game wants the cursor to be seen).

If I try to use SetCursor to set the cursor to an invisible one (and yes, I've used the related WM_ messages), the game still manages to get the cursor to show somehow, probably by using SetCursor.

I used a resource hacker to replace the cursor resource in the game executable with an invisible one, and that works, but I'd rather NOT change the game binaries.

Is there some way to modify the data pointed at by windows HCURSOR somehow at runtime?

(related question " [c++ modify resources at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339265/c-modify-resources-at-runtime) " changes the binary)

Comment: When you run a windows exe the resource section is mapped into memory as copy-on-write so you can change it.  At runtime overwrite the cursor's image data before the application loads the cursor.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my DLL gets called later than the application loads the cursor, but assuming it's not, how do I overwrite the cursor's image data?

Comment: Get a pointer to the cursor's image and mask and overwrite it with your image and mask.  Cursor resources have a somewhat elaborate layout which is basically the same as icon resource layout [as described here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/07/20/10331787.aspx).  Since you are dealing with an ancient binary that never changes you could calculate a (relative) pointer to the cursor data and code it into the wrapper.

Comment: Overwriting the data is the easy part, getting the pointer is the hard one =)